# React Native Expo - Custom Text Input has placeholder and input aligned vertically on iOS but not Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, jsx

I'm creating a custom text input, and everything is working fine on iOS with the placeholder text aligned vertically. But my custom component doesn't have the same effect on Android. I'm not sure where this could be modified in my styles or if there's some default padding going on for Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welp, I was right. It was some padding that Android adds to its text components INCLUDING the text placeholder. The good news is that there's a prop to easily fix this.

```
includeFontPadding: false
```